# Estimates in subpopulations with weighted data using survey() package

Tags: survey, weighted

ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/survey/vignettes/domain.pdf

The complete dataset is tch2012. However, I am only interested in the subpopulation of tch2012 in which two criteria are met: `age <= 5` and `gender == "female".` And within that subpopulation, I want to compare those with the disease `(disease == "1")` and without the disease `(disease == "0").`

This is the code I wrote:

```
library(survey)

tch2012.tsl.dsgn <- svydesign(id= ~HOSP_KID, strata= ~KID_STRATUM, weights = ~DISCWT, data = tch2012, nest = TRUE)
```

create a pointer to subpopulation of female pediatric age 5 years and under

```
tch2012_f_age5.tsl.dsgn <- subset(tch2012.tsl.dsgn, AGE <= 5 & gender == "female")
```

weighted data of total number with and without the disease in female pediatric patients age 5 years and under

```
svyby(~count, ~disease, design=tch2012_f_age5.tsl.dsgn, svytotal)
```

However, I got the below error message when I ran the svyby()

Error in `sum(sapply(covmats, ncol))` : invalid 'type' `(list)` of argument

Since I am not very familiar with dealing with weighted data, I am no clue how to trouble shoot.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

this code works

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
x <- subset( dclus1 , sch.wide == 'Yes' )
svyby(~api00, ~stype, design=x, svytotal)
```

please edit your question by adding a minimal reproducible example [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, Anthony. I have read your paper "Transitioning to R: Replicating SAS, Stata, and SUDAAN Analysis Techniques in Health Policy Data", which helped me a lot. I realized the mistake I made in my own programming.